# Get data from nested table using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

First of all this is my first question in the forum so please excuse me for any writing mistake.

I have 4 tables

[attaching the table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP4EN.jpg)

What I want is to get list of attraction name joining 'tblattraction' with 'tblattractionmaster' and count of the exact attraction for each place from 'tblattractions' using 'locationid' , I am using entity framework but don't know how to do that,

Disclaimer:
Each location can consist Multiple Places
Each Place can consist Multiple Attractions

What I have tried

```
 return context.tblLocationMasters.Select(t => new details()
                {
                    locationid = t.LocationId,
                    locationname = t.LocationName,
                    attractions =t.tblPlaces.SelectMany(a => a.tblAttractions).Select(b => new attractions(){
                        AttractionName=b.tblAttractionMaster.attractionname//(Not working),
                        TotalAttractions=0//???
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome! Your model seems wrong.. As I presume looking at your model, you have a self-relationship going on between tblattractions and tblattractionmaster. You can have only one Attraction table with a "parentId" field to get this behaviour.

Comment: @jpgrassi actually "tbllocation" can have multiple places so first I am joining "tblPaces" with "tblLocation" using "locationid", then a location can have multiple attractions sojoining "tblAttraction" with "tblPlaces" using "placeId" and finally I don't want to store the "AttractionName" in the "tblAttraction" as it will be repeated so "I am storing the name in the Master table called "tblAttractionMaster" and joining "tblAttraction" with "tblAttractionMaster" using "attrMasterId"

Comment: So, basically you want LocationId, LocationName, a count (and name) of the attraction in each place?

Comment: @jpgrassi yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your model (slightly different) using Code First. I came up with the following structure:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }

    public string PlaceName { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AttractionPlace> Attractions { get; set; }
}

public class Attraction
{
    public int AttractionId { get; set; }

    public string AttractionName { get; set; }
}

public class AttractionPlace
{
    public int AttractionPlaceId { get; set; }

    public int PlaceId { get; set; }

    public Place Place { get; set; }

    public int AttractionId { get; set; }

    public Attraction Attraction { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I could get the results in the way you needed with the following query:

```
var query = (from loc in db.Locations
             join pla in db.Places.Include(x => x.Attractions) on loc.LocationId equals pla.LocationId
             let count = pla.Attractions.Count()
             select new
             {
                 loc.LocationId,
                 loc.LocationName,
                 Attractions = pla.Attractions.Select(z => new
                 {
                     pla.PlaceName,
                     z.AttractionId,
                     z.Attraction.AttractionName
                 }),
                 AttractionsByPlaceCount = count
             });
```

The query above returns data in this [format](http://pastebin.com/JLSvvGvX)

**Just a side note though:** I didn't went further to see the performance of this query. The SQL generated by Linq wasn't that bad, but you should consider analyzing it before actually using it in production.

Comment: I think what you want is wrong. You said yourself that each location has many places and each place may has many attractions. So you can get place name and id and a sum of its attractions, but not attractioId and its sum. Makes sense?

Comment: actaually when user will select a country it will get all locations for that country and for each location I want show is the location name and all the distinct attractions with total count, for example user will select usa and I have two locations for usa like New York and Chicago for new york their are are 3 places for new york ex: "a" and "b" and "a" has 2 attractions like "x","y" and "b" has 1 attraction "x", show for the location New york I will show the name as  "New york" and will combine the attractions for both the place "a" and "b" will show distinct attractions with count

Comment: You'll have to work more on your model than. The way I imagines from your model Localtion would be USA, Place would be New York and Attraction would be Central Park. Now you said that Location is New York and Places are what? You can use the code and idea I provided to work more on your solution.